# SQL query executes successfully but no change is made

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update

I have a table with a `DateTime` column `Move_Date`. The dates are correct, but the time portion is zeroed out so I tried to replace the zeroed columns with the correct time. my query is as follows:

```
update TableA 
set Move_Date = replace(Move_Date, '00:00:00.000', '18:00:00.000')
```

When I run this query it succeeds with 1,632,380 rows affected, but no change has been made in the table at all. Is there something wrong with my query or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set the time portion:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET Move_Date = CAST(CAST(Move_Date AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('18:00' AS DATETIME)
-- WHERE CAST(Move_Date AS TIME) =  '00:00'
-- WHERE CAST(Move_Date AS TIME) <> '18:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I am curious as to why the query would return rows affected though.

Comment: `Move_Date`, a datetime, when used in string context e.g. `CONCAT(Move_Date, '')` would return a formatted date such as `Nov 19 2019  8:21PM`... there is no 00:00:00.000 to replace!

Answer (score 4):

For a `datetime` column, don't use string functions!  I think the simplest is `dateadd()`:

```
update TableA
    set Move_Date = dateadd(hour, 18, move_date);
```

If you only want to do this when the date is already midnight, then add a proper filter:

```
update TableA
    set Move_Date = dateadd(hour, 18, move_date)
    where move_date = convert(date, move_date);
```